# Build matrix from smaller matrices/vectors

Tags: c++, eigen

My final matrix **A** should be of size m x m, where I have two vectors **v**, **k** which are of size (m-1) and should be the first column and row respectively in **A**, excluding the element at (0, 0) which is 1. The remaining elements of **A** correspond to some matrix **M** of size (m-1) x (m-1).

## Example for 3 x 3 matrix

For the following components

```
 v = 2 2
 k = 3 3

 M = 4 4
     4 4
```

I would like to get

```
A = 1 2 2
    3 4 4
    3 4 4
```

**Note:** Elements of v, k and M can be arbitrary in reality.

## Code

My code looks the following for an example matrix of size 3 x 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(){

  Eigen::MatrixXd m;
  m.resize(3,3);

  Eigen::VectorXd v;
  v.resize(3);
  v[0] = 1 ;
  v[1] = 2;
  v[2] = 2;

  Eigen::VectorXd k;
  k.resize(3);
  k[0] = 1;
  k[1] = 3;
  k[2] = 3;

  Eigen::Matrix2d a = Eigen::Matrix2d::Constant(4);

  m.col(0) = k;
  m.row(0) = v;
  m.block<2,2>(1,1) = a;

  std::cout << m << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output looks like the following:

```
1 2 2
3 4 4
3 4 4
```

In the actual program the final matrix will be up to order 10^4 - 10^6. As I am fairly new to C++ I was wondering if this is the most efficient and elegant to do this and if I might run into trouble when it comes to larger matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `v` and `k` are `n x 1` vectors and `M` is a `n x n` matrix, you can write:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(M.rows()+1, M.cols()+1);
A << 1, v.transpose(),
     k, M;
```

This does almost the same as your code using `row`, `col` and `block`, but is probably more readable. And unless this happens inside a critical loop, I would not worry too much about performance here.

If this happens inside a critical loop, consider storing only `A` and access `M`, `v` and `k` by some block-expression.